# Sanitizing markup vs. "sandbox" in iframes

Tags: javascript, iframe, xss

I am looking to render user-generated HTML within an iframe. I am wondering if I should either (or both) sanitize the markup with a library like:

https://github.com/apostrophecms/sanitize-html

or just use the `sandbox` property on the iframe like so:

```
<iframe sandbox="allow-popups" srcdoc="myMarkup" />
```

Is one of these solutions better than the other or do they both accomplish the same thing?